# Android webview display mess

Tags: android, webview, android-websettings

I developing a browser using webview to load url,mostly showing perfect.
but some unexpected.some titles display at wrong place.
like below.

My browser
[image]

Other Browser
[image]

as you can see.on other browser.it running perfectly.so there must something i lost.

and this is my webview settings

```
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);//设置WebView是否可以运行JavaScript
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        settings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
    }

    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);//设置适应屏幕
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);//设置适应屏幕
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);//DOM缓存

    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);//设置WebView是否可以由JavaScript自动打开窗口,默认为false,通常与JavaScript的window.open()配合使用
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);//设置WebView是否支持多窗口
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);//设置是否支持缩放
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);//显示或不显示缩放按钮(wap网页不支持)
    settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);//启用或禁用WebView访问文件数据
    settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```

who can tell how to fix this.

Comment: what is your android version ?

Comment: @MithunSarkerShuvro Android6.0,running on other device is perfect.

Comment: Is all url display mess or just this url ? Just try loading some other url and check if you get the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem only with specific url, which language is other than english, then try the following

```
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: not working.not specific url,i found another website display kind like this.